# Npm install eror

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Having an issue with npm install on my project. Used to be ok just few days ago.

Solutions like

> npm cache clean —force

> deleted node-modules

> package-lock.json

> npm install

Those steps havent helps.

I have created gist so you could see the error and maybe understand more then i do.

Many thanks in advance.

https://gist.github.com/ladygo93/c2c5c87759bc33210866418e457165d3

**FIXED**

So had an upgrade to `node.js` 16+, forced `node-sass` to *v6.0.1*
while upgrading `react-scripts` manually to *v4.0.3* from *v4.0.0*  that way issue is gone for now.

Comment: Instead of using a gist, please post it here in code blocks. Links can break, which would render this question useless.

Comment: Have you recently updated node.js version?

Answer (score 2):

Older version of node-sass don't work with new versions of Node.js. You can find the exact version requirements [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy). Similarly, newer versions on npm use newer version of Node.js (see [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)). And in fact, npm is bundled in the Node.js installer.

If node-sass is a dependency defined in your package.json, updating to a newer version should fix the error. If node-sass is a transitive dependency or if you cannot update it because of compatibility issues, you'll have to stick to the old versions of Node.js and npm.

Comment: hi, so I came back to older node version, locally everything started to work as it should, while in GitHub CI Build is failed. looks like CI runs newer version for npm install and that's why it fails, maybe you have idea how to fix it ? 
[link]https://gist.github.com/ladygo93/98e1dc538ade48155beb688a2c54a6fc  - error link

Comment: What version of node-sass are you using?

Comment: 4.14.1. At the moment

Comment: node-sass 4.14.1 only works with Node 14, you have Node 16 now.

Comment: Fixed and yes that was the issue. Just needed to upgrade react-scripts together with node-sass

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the older version of npm used in the production. You can do it two ways:

1: Install the older version of npm using `npm -g install npm@6`
2: Use `npx` to install a different version of npm while keeping the current version of npm in your system. Use command `npx -p npm@6`

Comment: Would that also fix the problem in CI Build on pull request in github? As i get same error

Comment: Try this, Make sure the node_modules has the lock file by `npm ci`  Once it is done, remove your package-lock.json and install the newer version of npm `npm install`. This will recreate your package-lock.json file. Commit the update to your repo/docker.

Comment: hello again, i came back to node version 14.17.6 , npm version 6.14.15
don't have problems locally anymore, but CI build is still failed. Any ideas maybe ?  here is new gist with error from ci build.
[link]https://gist.github.com/ladygo93/98e1dc538ade48155beb688a2c54a6fc
I have done `npm ci`  as you advised and package-lock.json was deleted too